# Who were the two priests of Asuras (not Shukracharya)?

Tags: brahmins, asuras, shatapatha-brahmana, manu

I came across an interesting story while reading the **[Shatapatha brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1206.htm)** regarding Manu's encounters with the priests of Asuras:

> 14. Manu was in possession of a bull. Into him had entered an Asura-killing, foe-killing voice; and by his snorting and roaring the Asuras and Rakshas were continually being crushed. Thereupon the Asuras said to one another: 'Evil, alas! this bull inflicts upon us! how can we possibly destroy him?' Now **Kilâta and Âkuli were the two priests (brahman) of the Asuras.**

These two sacrificed the bull to put an end to the above mentioned voice and **I want to know who these two priests of the Asuras are?**

Comment: First time I am hearing of these two, always thought Shukracharya only as their priest. Thanks for asking this question SIr,

Comment: Yes I also read about them for the first time in the Shatpatha Brahman.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal I think they are vedic versions of Sanda and Marka.