# Who was the wife of Manu who was sacrificed by the priests of the Asuras?

Tags: asuras, sacrifice, shatapatha-brahmana, manu, priests

I came across an interesting story while reading the **[Shatapatha brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1206.htm)** regarding Manu's encounters with the priests of Asuras about whose identity I had asked a [separate question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29129/who-were-the-two-priests-of-asuras-not-shukracharya). These two had sacrificed the bull of Manu that had a voice that could kill Asuras but then something interesting happened:

> 15. These two said, 'God-fearing, they say, is Manu: let us two then ascertain!' They then went to him and said: 'Manu! we will sacrifice for thee!' He said: 'Wherewith?' They said: 'With this bull!' He said: 'So be it!' **On his (the bull's) being killed the voice went from him.**

This Asura-killing sound went from the bull to Manu's wife who is mentioned simply as Manavi (of Manu):

> 16. **It entered into Manâvî, the wife of Manu; and when they heard her speak, the Asuras and Rakshas were continually being crushed.** Thereupon the Asuras said to one another: 'Hereby even greater evil is inflicted on us, for the human voice speaks more!' Kilâta and Âkuli then said: 'God-fearing, they say, is Manu: let us then ascertain!' **They went to him and said: 'Manu! we will sacrifice for thee!' He said: 'Wherewith?'They said: 'With this thy wife!' He said: 'So be it!' And on her being killed that voice went from her.**

I am interested in this last portion that says Manavi was also sacrificed after the bull. **I want to know Who was this wife of Manu who was sacrificed by the priests of the Asuras?**

Comment: Sir does the scripture mention which Manu was this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. it just mentions Manu and Manvi thats why I want to know more. Had the name of either of them been given finding details of the spouse would have become easier.