# Who was Parâvasu the former Hotri for Asuras?

Tags: scripture, asuras, shatapatha-brahmana, priests

**[Shatapatha Brahmana 1.5.1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1222.htm)** mentions an interesting thing about the priests of the Devas and Asuras:

> 23. He steps beside the Hotri's seat, takes one stalk of (reed) grass from the Hotri's seat and casts it outside (the sacrificial ground), with the formula, 'Ejected is the wealth-clutcher (parâvasu, lit. "off-wealth")!' **Formerly, namely, the Hotri of the Asuras was one Parâvasu by name: him he thereby ejects from the Hotri's seat.**
> 24. He then sits down on the Hotri's seat, with the formula, 'I here sit down on the seat of the wealth-bestower (arvâvasu, lit. "hither-wealth")!' for one Arvâvasu by name was the Hotri of the gods, and on his seat he accordingly sits down.

The former Hotri of the Devas could be one of the [three previous Agnis](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29162/what-is-the-story-of-the-three-previous-agnis-who-passed-away) I asked a question for but I want to know about **Who is this Parâvasu who was the former Hotri for the Asuras and how did he become their Hotri?**

If it helps another section of the same scripture also mentions [two priests of the Asuras](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29129/who-were-the-two-priests-of-asuras-not-shukracharya) that I had asked a question about earlier and this guy could be one of those but I want to know it conclusively through scriptural references.

Comment: AFAIK Arvavasu and Paravasu are the son of Raibhya.

Comment: Oh that's good to know can you please share a reference for this as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Tirtha-yatra Parva: SECTION CXXXV](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03135.htm), Paravasu and Arvavasu were the son of Raivya (or Raibhya).

> "Lomasa said, 'Bharadwaja and Raivya were two friends. And they dwelt here, ever taking the greatest pleasure in each other's company. Now, **Raivya had two sons, named Arvavasu and Paravasu**. And, Bharadwaja, O Bharata's son, had an only son, named Yavakri.

Comment: Great.. at least we now know who these people were! Please add any other details that you may find regarding them as well.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Yes, I will add more references in some time.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal so this is a third priest of the Asuras besides the other two you mentioned in another question?

Comment: Yes my friend apparently there have been many priests of the Asuras